# How to set a keepalive in PgAdmin4?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

It was possible in PgAdmin-III to set a keepalive through the `~/.pg_services.conf` file. Looking at the docs for version 4, it doesn't seem to use libpq and there is no mention of a keepalive setting in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

TCP settings could be configured in : `postgresql.conf`

- On Ubuntu it would be found in: `/etc/postgresql/13/main/` (note that "13" refers to postgresql version)

Set the `tcp_keepalives_idle` based on [official document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/runtime-config-connection.html) and your experience on how much does it take to disconnect. Example: 480

Based on my experience, using SSH-Tunneling is the best way to keep the connection alive.

- You might either set up a SSH-Tunneling using PuTTY (windows) or terminal (Ubuntu) like: `ssh -L 63333:localhost:5432 user@VPS-IP/Domain`
  and then use localhost and port 63333 to connect from pgAdmin.
- Or you can use the pgAgmin built-in SSH-Tunneling.

Note: The SSH itself should be kept alive by creating a config file in .ssh/ and proper settings like:

```
Host (VPS-IP)
   Hostname (VPS-IP)
   Port 22
   User (your username)
   ServerAliveInterval 180
   ServerAliveCountMax 2
```